# What is requesting my azure servicebus queue

Tags: azure, azureservicebus, azure-servicebus-queues

I am using a service bus queue that uses sessions, and currently, something is receiving and deleting my messages.

The problem is that I don't know what is requesting the service bus queue.

**Is there someway for me to see what/who is requesting my Azure service bus queue?**

let me know if you need more information.

Comment: I would _hope_ you _know_ who you gave Shared Access Policy details to. Recycle them to see who's coming to complain :).

Comment: We all stopped what we have that is normally requesting it and something is still doing so. It is on our Dev environment so probably someone forgot they have something running somewhere. 
Hope this made sense?

Comment: I understand the question, but I think it is not available... Even the [Service Bus diagnostic logs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-bus-messaging/service-bus-diagnostic-logs) don't provide any information about the connected client.

Comment: Guess it's time to get it up to use SAS then

Answer (score 0):

If you have shared the SAS token and now you don't want to do that. I recommand that you could regenerate the policy key from Azure portal.

[image]

Comment: Sadly we run on the old ACS and it is probably running on the owner key

Comment: According to your description, it seems that someone use your owner key. Sorry I don't have experience about old ACS. But If regenerate key is possible, I still recommand that you  regenerate it.